# How to boot from an .img file using grub?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, grub

I wanted to boot my computer from an image file, where this file has permission to: read / write, so that when I turn off, my files are saved inside this file.

I know that this is possible because it has to mount as loop using: `sudo losetup / dev / loop9 disk.img`. For example I will be able to start a file with MS-Windows even if the file system (on the hard disk) is ext4, since the file will be fat32, and also I can mount this file inside linux and also modify it, making it very easy to test different operating systems, without "breaking" the computer. Would anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as an `img` file. What sort of image is it. What file-system, partitioning etc?

Comment: This question is not clear: originally one sentence, and some jumbled ideas. It seems to fills my head with ideas, only I don't exactly know what they are. You seem to be asking about booting from a removable file-system, that is read/write, that much is clear. There is also stuff about MS-Windows, Linux, fat32, ext4, loop, however I don't know where any of this fits in.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  Excuse me, I used Google Translate, because I don't speak English naturally, I speak Portuguese, I recognize that you were confused, but I just want to boot from an .img file, which is a hard disk file.

Comment: there is no judgement. I am only trying to help. Make the Portuguese original as clear and well written as possible. Google translate works by finding patterns in books that were translated by humans. Therefore writing in the style of these book will produce the best results. Use good grammar, punctuation, proofread, then translate.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Linux-Avancado/Como-dar-boot-a-partir-de-um-arquivo-img-usando-Grub escrevi aqui em portugues, esta bem explicado, resumo: quero montar e dar boot em um arquivo .img, (não postei aqui pois o forum me proibe, de fazer isso, minha questão é deletada em questão de 1 minuto,por estar em portugues), desde já agradeço  a ajuda.